# Coupling vs Decoupling filter / Filter in-the-signal-path vs filter on-the-signal-path

Tags: analog, filter

I'm looking at designing an active analog filter module to be used/reused in my designs. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can design a filter that is in the signal path that has the same frequency domain properties as a filter that is simply a bypass to ground. What are the advantages/disadvantages of both types of filters?

This is for non-RF circuits under 30V with low current.

Comment: Interesting question. Did you come to any conclusions since asking it?